# How to Use throbber properly?

Tags: android

I need to include in my application a throbber. 
I can`t use it

ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading", "Wait while loading...");

in my AsyncTask, because every time I want to use it I get aa error:

The method show(Context, CharSequence, CharSequence) in the type ProgressDialog is not applicable for the arguments (MainActivity.GetRSSDataTask, String, String).

I need it working while parcing. 
help..

```
 static class GetRSSDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<RssItem> > {

     MainActivity activity;

     void link(MainActivity act) {
          activity = act;
        }

     void unLink() {
          activity = null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading", "Wait while loading...");          
        } // ERROR show is lined red
```

Comment: Show the code where the error happens, or the stacktrace.

Comment: By the way, what's "throbber"?

Comment: @Egor - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throbber

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are passing `this` as first argument of `show()` inside from an `AsyncTask`, but that is not a `Context` instance; try to pass a reference to the `MainActivity` class instead.

**EDIT:** I see you added the code; in your case you have to pass the `activity` variable.